# How to Get Active Excel Instance?

Tags: c#, excel

I have an application in C#, this application paste info to excel on user demand, the logic behind is like this, if there are none excel instances running, it creates one and paste to that instance.

If there is only one instance running, it tries to get that instance and work with it. This is the code I'm using to do so:

```
Guid _guid;
CLSIDFromProgID("Excel.Application", out _guid);
if (_guid == Guid.Empty) {...}
IntPtr _ptr = new IntPtr();
GetActiveObject(ref _guid, _ptr, out objApp);
```

So far everythig works fine, but the problem that I have is when there are more than one excel instances running, I want to get the active instance of Excel, but currently I'm only able to get the first instance that I opened, which is the first instance registered in the Running Object Table according to what I read.

Is there a way to "ask" to an excel instance if it is the active instance and thus use it? or how can I get the active instance?

Comment: What's your definition of active? Has focus? What if another app has focus? You might just have to ask the user which instance to use...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all possibilities to get hold of or to start Excel see this blog post by Andrew Whitechapel:

> [Launching Office Apps Programmatically](http://blogs.msdn.com/andreww/archive/2008/11/30/starting-or-connecting-to-office-apps.aspx)

If you can get a window handle of the "active" Excel instance you might want to try `AccessibleObjectFromWindow` which will give you access to the OM.

Answer (score -1):

I've created a class that can iterate through all running Excel instances, and lookup by Hwnd, ProcessID, or a Process object.  It also has a property to return the "Active" instance (according to the Marshal class) which is the instance that double-clicked Excel file icons will open in, as well as the top-most instance, which is the instance with the top-most window.

The code is below, but check this link for further description.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1080611/Get-a-Collection-of-All-Running-Excel-Instances

This has not been tested on all versions of Excel or Windows.

---

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

//Don't add the entire interop namespace, it will introduce some naming conflicts.
using xlApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;
using xlWin = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Window;

namespace ExcelExtensions {

    /// <summary>
    /// Collection of currently running Excel instances.
    /// </summary>
    public class ExcelAppCollection : IEnumerable<xlApp>  {

        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the 
        /// <see cref="ExcelAppCollection"/> class.</summary>
        /// <param name="sessionID">Windows sessionID to filter instances by.
        /// If not assigned, uses current session.</param>
        public ExcelAppCollection (Int32? sessionID = null) {
            if (sessionID.HasValue && sessionID.Value < -1)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("sessionID");

            this.SessionID = sessionID
                ?? Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>Gets the Windows sessionID used to filter instances.
        /// If -1, uses instances from all sessions.</summary>
        /// <value>The sessionID.</value>
        public Int32 SessionID { get; private set; }

        #endregion

        #region Accessors

        /// <summary>Gets the Application associated with a given process.</summary>
        /// <param name="process">The process.</param>
        /// <returns>Application associated with process.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">process</exception>
        public xlApp FromProcess(Process process) {
            if (process == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("process");
            return InnerFromProcess(process);
        }

        /// <summary>Gets the Application associated with a given processID.</summary>
        /// <param name="processID">The process identifier.</param>
        /// <returns>Application associated with processID.</returns>
        public xlApp FromProcessID(Int32 processID) {
            try {
                return FromProcess(Process.GetProcessById(processID));
            }
            catch (ArgumentException) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Get the Application associated with a given window handle.</summary>
        /// <param name="mainHandle">The window handle.</param>
        /// <returns>Application associated with window handle.</returns>
        public xlApp FromMainWindowHandle(Int32 mainHandle) {
            return InnerFromHandle(ChildHandleFromMainHandle(mainHandle));
        }

        /// <summary>Gets the main instance. </summary>
        /// <remarks>This is the oldest running instance.
        /// It will be used if an Excel file is double-clicked in Explorer, etc.</remarks>
        public xlApp PrimaryInstance {
            get {
                try {
                    return Marshal.GetActiveObject(MarshalName) as xlApp;
                }
                catch (COMException) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Gets the top most instance.</summary>
        /// <value>The top most instance.</value>
        public xlApp TopMostInstance {
            get {
                var topMost = GetProcesses() //All Excel processes
                    .Select(p => p.MainWindowHandle) //All Excel main window handles
                    .Select(h => new { h = h, z = GetWindowZ(h) }) //Get (handle, z) pair per instance
                    .Where(x => x.z > 0) //Filter hidden instances
                    .OrderBy(x => x.z) //Sort by z value
                    .First(); //Lowest z value

                return FromMainWindowHandle(topMost.h.ToInt32());
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>Returns an enumerator that iterates through the collection.</summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// A <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1" /> 
        /// that can be used to iterate through the collection.
        /// </returns>
        public IEnumerator<xlApp> GetEnumerator() {
            foreach (var p in GetProcesses())
                yield return FromProcess(p);
        }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }

        /// <summary>Gets all Excel processes in the current session.</summary>
        /// <returns>Collection of all Excel processing in the current session.</returns>
        public IEnumerable<Process> GetProcesses() {

            IEnumerable<Process> result = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName);

            if (this.SessionID >= 0)
                result = result.Where(p => p.SessionId == SessionID);

            return result;
        }

        #endregion

    //--------Implementation

        #region Methods

            private static xlApp InnerFromProcess(Process p) {
                return InnerFromHandle(ChildHandleFromMainHandle(p.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32()));
            }

            private static Int32 ChildHandleFromMainHandle(Int32 mainHandle) {
                Int32 handle = 0;
                EnumChildWindows(mainHandle, EnumChildFunc, ref handle);
                return handle;
            }

            private static xlApp InnerFromHandle(Int32 handle) {
                xlWin win = null;
                Int32 hr = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(handle, DW_OBJECTID, rrid.ToByteArray(), ref win);
                return win.Application;
            }

            private static Int32 GetWindowZ(IntPtr handle) {
                var z = 0;
                for (IntPtr h = handle; h != IntPtr.Zero; h = GetWindow(h, GW_HWNDPREV))
                    z++;
                return z;
            }

            private static Boolean EnumChildFunc(Int32 hwndChild, ref Int32 lParam) { 
                var buf = new StringBuilder(128); 
                GetClassName(hwndChild, buf, 128); 
                if (buf.ToString() == ComClassName) { 
                    lParam = hwndChild; 
                    return false; 
                } 
                return true; 
            }

            #endregion

            #region Extern Methods

            [DllImport("Oleacc.dll")] 
            private static extern Int32 AccessibleObjectFromWindow(
                Int32 hwnd, UInt32 dwObjectID, Byte[] riid, ref xlWin ptr); 

            [DllImport("User32.dll")] 
            private static extern Boolean EnumChildWindows(
                Int32 hWndParent, EnumChildCallback lpEnumFunc, ref Int32 lParam); 

            [DllImport("User32.dll")] 
            private static extern Int32 GetClassName(
                Int32 hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, Int32 nMaxCount); 

            [DllImport("User32.dll")] 
            private static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 uCmd);

            #endregion

            #region Constants & delegates

            private const String MarshalName = "Excel.Application";

            private const String ProcessName = "EXCEL";

            private const String ComClassName = "EXCEL7";

            private const UInt32 DW_OBJECTID = 0xFFFFFFF0;

            private const UInt32 GW_HWNDPREV = 3;
            //3 = GW_HWNDPREV
            //The retrieved handle identifies the window above the specified window in the Z order.
            //If the specified window is a topmost window, the handle identifies a topmost window.
            //If the specified window is a top-level window, the handle identifies a top-level window.
            //If the specified window is a child window, the handle identifies a sibling window.

            private static Guid rrid = new Guid("{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");

            private delegate Boolean EnumChildCallback(Int32 hwnd, ref Int32 lParam);
            #endregion
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome. Please post the code in your answer, as then it will still be useful if the link should break.