# How do I get a reference to a specific instance of Excel Application

Tags: c#, excel

The following code works with a chart that the user has selected in Excel:

```
Excel.Application XlApp = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
Excel.Workbook XlWb = XlApp.ActiveWorkbook;
Excel.Chart XlChart = XlApp.ActiveChart;
```

It works fine when only one Excel application is running. But how do I get a  reference to the `Excel.Application` or `Excel.Workbook` that contains the activated chart when more than one `Excel.Application` is executing?

Comment: I presume the situation here is that the user has opened Excel and your application gets a reference to that running instance via `GetActiveObject`. This presumably works fine until the user opens another second instance of excel? Can you tell us more about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Users work with charts on many Excel worksheets and workbooks at the same time. Sometimes theese workbooks are opened in many Excel.Applications. But  GetActiveObject() return reference to first-opened  Excel.Application. I just need to work with chart, that was clicked last.

Comment: Yes I get that, but why? What is the purpose of your application?

Comment: One of functions of my application: get chart, add some stuff on it, change some sizes, fonts, formats and after that save chart as picture.

Comment: "I just need to work with chart, that was clicked last." - so you mean grab the chart from the instance of Excel that has the current window focus. Otherwise how will you know which Excel app to attach to?

Comment: Almost. But when user clicks on the button on my form - it gets focus. Correct me if i'm wrong, please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Get Active Excel Instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756951/how-to-get-active-excel-instance)